# ASCII terminal simulation using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a Java Swing-based simulation for a typical ASCII-based terminal. I have a content of the terminal screen as a 2-dimensional array where each element has a character plus foreground and background color.

The initial (naive) strategy was to have a `JPanel` and use its `paintComponent(...)` method to simply draw each individual character from the array using `drawString(...)` method at a specific coordinate (with the appropriate foreground and background color handling as well as necessary font metrics arithmetic).

It works fine - but painfully, unusably slow (especially if I maximize the window size).

Am I missing something obvious design wise?

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mre] as a part of your question, but my guess is that you're blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) with `Thread.sleep` or some long-running process.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect performance issues in your code, you might want to check out Java Swing's builtin JEditorPane. It can handle long documents with various formatting of text, or even embedded other objects like images.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html